# Good project layout for a ruby system project?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am writing small Ruby program that is used to backup some folders and send to s3,

e.g.

```
backup.rb --folder /folder1 --folder /folder1 ...-c config.ini
```

Before I start writing this program from scratch, I want to know if there is some existing good sample project layout that I can reference?

e.g. how to layout the `tests, libraries, classes, configs, doc` etc

I am particularly interested in a layout that **allow me to share the libraries so later I can easily re-use in other project.**, even submit to ruby gems

Would be helpful if anyone can send me some good examples from existing OSS.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty standard structure. Drawn from [RubyGem Tutorial](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)

```
.
  bin/    # Executables here
  data/   # Assets here
  doc/    # RDOC for the lib directory
  lib/    # Code for the project
    project_module.rb # Contains project module
    project_module/   # Classes for project module

  # Either
  spec/   # RSpec Tests
  test/   # Test::Unit Tests
```